# Correct python kolmogorov smirnov syntax

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov

If I have a column of ages and want to test for normality, what is the correct syntax for kolmogorov smirnov?  Would it be A, B, or C?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kstest

loc = np.mean(ages)
scale = np.std(ages)
std_ages = (ages - loc) / scale

teststat, p_value = kstest(rvs = ages, cdf = 'norm', args = (loc, scale)) #A
teststat, p_value = kstest(rvs = ages, cdf = 'norm')                      #B
teststat, p_value = kstest(rvs = std_ages, cdf = 'norm')                  #C
```

Comment: Did you try _running_ them? What happened?

Comment: Yes, they all work and in my case the ages are non-normal so I knew the answer before, but in reading the documentation it isn't clear the correct syntax.  When googling the answer, everything I saw was using made up data such as stats.norm.rvs, etc. so still not sure the correct code.